# Either / Or option Karate response json item

Tags: karate

I am running the following GET command:

```
    And param fields = "Name,Category,Type,Item,InstanceId"
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

From the response I would like to check if "Item" is either of type "PaaS" or "Technical Service"

```
   And match response.instances[0].attributes.Item == ['PaaS', 'Technical Service']
```

When executing the feature file I am getting the following error

```
18 - path: $.instances[0].attributes.Item, actual: 'PaaS', expected: ["PaaS","Technical Service"], reason: actual value is not list-like
```

This means to me  it's an AND relationship. How can I check if the attribute is **EITHER** PaaS **OR** Technical Service